# How to add two fields on one add another items?

Tags: entities, 6, ajax

I have 2 fields with unlimited values both fields show its own add another items button.
i am trying todo is add both fields add with one add another items button.

Comment: Maybe you could try http://drupal.org/project/field_collection ?

Comment: i am using drupal 6 :( any drupal 6 version?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't realize , I can't help you with D6...

Answer (score 3):

CCK version 6.x-3.0-alpha3 contains a module called Multigroup. It allows you to group multiple fields together and repeat that group of fields multiple times with a single add-another button. This is an alpha version though, so if you decide to use it, test well to make sure it doesn't break something else.

Comment: i already trying this but its break my site.

Answer (score 1):

This post is a bit old, but I needed this info so someone else might as well.

For Drupal 7, install the [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module.
Go to your form and add a field of type "Field Collection".
Give this field unlimited values.
This field is the container that all of your other fields will be in.

Then go to Structure >> Field Collections

and find the field that you just created. Add your inner fields into this form. That's it!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.poplarware.com/articles/cck_field_module As an option, you can write own compound field.
However, I'd suggest you to investigate why multigroup not working and fix this.

Answer (score 0):

For this trick you can use follow modules:

- [Field group multiple](http://drupal.org/project/field_group_multiple)
- [Field collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection)

I prefer **Field group multiple** module.